# Ubuntu Server driver source catalog

Tags: server, drivers

Where do I find this drivers on my .iso image for the server software, or what is the ftp: location to download these files as those are the two options i am given on how to solve this issue.

ubuntu-server 11.10, hardware: dell r210 what I am reading is that I am possibly missing 'mpt2sas' driver somewhere in this boot disc. I'm attempting to download a different version in the hopes that the mistake I made was downloading software meant for an AMD architecture.

Comment: What "server software" or driver are you trying to install ? Everything you need should be on the .iso or in the repositories.

Comment: ubuntu-server 11.10,
hardware: dell r210
 what I am reading is that I am possibly missing 'mpt2sas' driver somewhere in this boot disc.  I'm attempting to download a different version in the hopes that the mistake I made was downloading software meant for an AMD architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a kernel bug and suggest you file a bug report. [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Similar reports in Launchpad (there are others)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/906873